# Permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket

Tags: ubuntu, docker, unix-socket

On Ubuntu 16.04 LTS whenever trying using docker login command the following warring message will be show :

```
docker login
Warning: failed to get default registry endpoint from daemon (Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Get http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.30/info: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied). Using system default: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Login with your Docker ID to push and pull images from Docker Hub. If you don't have a Docker ID, head over to https://hub.docker.com to create one.
Username: csomethingr
Password: 
Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Post http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.30/auth: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied
```

Any solution?

Comment: It looks like you're not part of the Docker group in Ubuntu. Check to see if you're part of the group by running `getent group docker`. If you're not part of the group, add yourself by running `sudo usermod -a -G docker <your_username>`

Comment: `sudo docker login` or as @Serey mentioned add your user to docker group

Comment: It;s working. Thank you @Tarun Lalwani

Answer (score 31, accepted):

use `sudo docker login`

or as @Serey mentioned add your user to docker group

```
usermod -aG docker $USER
```

and disconect from your session!

Comment: and remember to logout/login to your shell after the usermod so it takes effect.

Answer (score 11):

To use docker in the user mode use the following command:

```bash
sudo chmod 666 /var/run/docker.sock
```

Answer (score 6):

you have to add the user to the docker group as the other posts suggest

```sh
usermod -aG docker $USER
```

This change won't affect your current terminal session however. If you don't want to login/logout you can use

```sh
newgrp - docker
```

for the change to affect to your current terminal session.

Answer (score 4):

Once I have tried that solution .initially it didnt work, but it worked after RESTART of whole system.

Comment: Same here, but restart helped.